# Best way to add Camel route to encrypt and sign based on file name

Tags: encryption, apache-camel, sign, pgp

Based on file name prefix, I want to PGP encrypt and sign with different keys. I can use multiple encryption routes and direct them using a [Message Router](http://camel.apache.org/message-router.html). Do anyone know a way to avoid multiple routs and get the related PGP keys at route running time?

```
final PGPDataFormat encryptAndSign01 = new PGPDataFormat();
encryptAndSign01.setKeyFileName(conf.pgpPublicKeyFile);
encryptAndSign01.setKeyUserid(conf.pgpEncryptUser01);
encryptAndSign01.setSignatureKeyFileName(conf.pgpPrivateKeyFile);
encryptAndSign01.setSignatureKeyUserid(conf.pgpSignUser01);
encryptAndSign01.setSignaturePassword(conf.pgpSignUser01Passphrase);

from("encrypt01")
    .marshal(encryptAndSign01)
    .to("file:tmp/output?fileName=${file:name}.pgp");

...

from("file:tmp/output?include=output.*.csv")
    .choice()
        .when(...)
            .to(direct:encrypt01)
        .when(...)
            .to(direct:encrypt02);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the parameters of encryption by using the message header just like [this](http://camel.apache.org/crypto.html#Crypto-PGPDataFormatMessageHeaders)
But I think it could be more easy if you use different routes to do the job.